# My merge sort code is completely correct, yet no sorting is taking place

Tags: java, mergesort

I have a     `public static int Dlist[ ][ ]`     declared in the class and the below mentioned functions are written.

I saw a similar code (only the basic mergesort code on GeeksforGeeks) where they take k = 1 and their code works completely welll. where as, my does something but the result is not what is expected. i am not able to understand why k=1 working ?

I'd like to know two things.

1) why k = 1 works (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-program-for-merge-sort/)

Shouldn't it be `k = 0` and instead of `arr[k]` it should have been `arr[l+k]`

2) What is the problem in my code? Why is it not doing anything?

*Also LI is left indes, RI is right index, MI is middle index, ii is for Dlist[ ][ii]

```
public static void mergeSort(int Dlist[][], int ii, int li, int ri)
{
    if(ri > li)
    {
        int m = (li+ri)/2;

        mergeSort(Dlist, ii, li, m);
        mergeSort(Dlist, ii, m + 1, ri);

        Merge(Dlist, ii, li, m, ri); 
    }
}

public static void Merge(int Dlist[][], int ii, int li, int m, int ri)
{
    int la[][] = new int[m-li+1][2];
    int ra[][] = new int[ri-m][2];
    int i,j,k;

    for(i = 0; i < m-li+1; i++)
    {
        la[i][0] = Dlist[li+i][0];
        la[i][1] = Dlist[li+i][1];
    }

    for(i = 0; i < ri-m; i++)
    {
        ra[i][0] = Dlist[m+i+1][0];
        ra[i][1] = Dlist[m+i+1][1];
    }

    i = 0; j = 0; k = 0;

    while ((i < m-li+1) && (j < m-ri))
    {
        if(la[i][ii] < ra[j][ii])
        {
            Dlist[(li+k)][ii] = la[i][ii];
            if(ii == 1)
            {
                Dlist[(li+k)][0] = la[i][0];
            }
            i++;
            k++;
        }
        else
        {
            Dlist[(li+k)][ii] = ra[j][ii];
            if(ii == 1)
            {
                Dlist[(li+k)][0] = ra[j][0];
            }
            j++;
            k++;
        }
    }

    while (i < m-li+1)
    {
        Dlist[li+k][ii] = la[i][ii];
        if(ii == 1)
        {
            Dlist[li+k][0] = la[i][0];
        }
        i++;
        k++;
    }

    while (j < m-ri)
    {
        Dlist[li+k][ii] = ra[j][ii];
        if(ii == 1)
        {
            Dlist[li+k][0] = ra[j][0];
        }
        j++;
        k++;
    }
}
```

The aim of the code is to convert this :-

*The sorting is done with respect to `Dlist[ ][1]` in descending order.

```
2 4 5 7 8
4 2 7 9 1
```

into this :-

```
7 5 2 4 8
9 7 4 2 1
```

But the functions don't do anything.

Final Update :-

I was able to make the same code work by copying `Dlist[][1]` to another array. Then applying those functions on this new copied array and in merge function, while modifying copied array, i made same modifications in Dlist. Don't know why it worked that way. But that worked for me.

Comment: It would easier to tell what is going wrong if you use variable names that _mean_ something, this is horrible to read because none of your variables mean anything.  You also don't follow Java naming conventions for variable names and use all capital letter for parameters, I suggest you look up those guidelines.

Comment: very sorry for this issue.... i have never learned how to name variables..T_T

Comment: WIll definetly learn it now

Comment: Also LI is left indes, RI is right index, MI is middle index, ii is for Dlist[ ][ii]

Comment: Yeah but if you need to describe what your variables are or a comment to explain what it is, you probably do not have a good name for that variable.  Also the article you link does not use proper naming convention either and names an array `R`, variable names do _not_ start with a capital letter.  They also have bad names otherwise and I would only use it to learn the logic of the algorithm and not follow the way they write their code.  You will find it much easier to understand your own code in the future if you follow the guidelines.

Comment: If you are sure that your code is correct but it doesn't *do* anything then either (a) it is not correct (b) you are not *using* it. To help us determine which is it please take your time and provide proper [MCVE] (a.k.a. [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) - code which we could copy-paste and without doing *any* modifications run and get same problem you are having).

Comment: @HARSHILJAIN Learning how to name variable isn't hard. You said _"Also LI is left indes, RI is right index, MI is middle index, ii is for Dlist[ ][ii]"_ why not replace "LI" with "leftIndex", "RI" with "rightIndex" and "MI" with "middleIndex" and so on. Do not use obsure abbreviation like you are texting. If you want to use short name make sure they are widely understood. Like temp for Temperature etc....

Comment: @HARSHILJAIN The only thing that you need to remember is in Java we use camelCase to name everthing. For classes we use UpperCamelCase (First letter of everyword is uppercase) for rest we use lowerCamelCase (The first word is all lower case but for remaining first letter is uppercase).

Comment: Where is the Msort function (lines 7,8) defined? Is it supposed to be mergeSort?

Comment: When you say 'completely correct' all you can really mean is 'compiles successfully'. If it really was completely correct it would execute correctly and you wouldn't be asking this question.

Answer (score 0):

It's not `k = 1`, it's `k = l` (in upper case `K = L`).

`mergeSort(Dlist, ii, m + 1, mi);` should be `mergeSort(Dlist, ii, m + 1, ri);`

Regardless if ii == 0 or ii == 1, merge should always copy DList[..][0] and DList[..][1].

The code would be simpler if ri was the ending index (last index + 1), eliminating all the `+1` in the code. You could change the index names to bgn or bi (instead of li) and end or ei (instead of ri).

Take a look at the wiki example for top down merge sort. It does a one time copy of the original array, into a one time allocated working array, then swaps the array names in the recursive calls so that the direction of merge corresponds to the level of recursion, eliminating the need to create sub-arrays or copy back. It also passes the beginning and ending indexes (as opposed to beginning and last index), and in the initial call beginning index = 0 and ending index = size of array (`n`).

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Top-down_implementation

Comment: regarding mi and ri, actuall i was editing this code on this website, so by mistake i changed ri to mi. i have corrected it now.